# How to swipe image change on iPad with less memory and CPU load?

Tags: ipad, memory, cpu, swipe

My app has around 100 Picture. Each picture is around 150 KB.And I just want to swipe each picture to go next or back to previous pic.

What is the best way that use less memory and CPU load ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** you have all images within application, all image names stored in NSMutableArray.

Take one UIImageView wired up as IBOutlet on your XIB file.

```
NSMutableArray *imgNameArr; //Array to store image names
NSInteger currShowing; //Integer value to keep track of image currently being displayed.

//Function to change image when swipe right
-(void)swipeRight
{
    if(currShowing<[imgNameArr count])
    {
        currShowing+=1;
        self.yourDisplayImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgNameArr objectAtIndex:currShowing]];
    }
}

//Function to change image when swipe left
-(void)swipeLeft
{
    if(currShowing>0)
    {
        currShowing-=1;
        self.yourDisplayImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgNameArr objectAtIndex:currShowing]];
    }
}
```

Please do leave comment for any query.

Hope it helps.